# Why isn't this creating a new line? PHP

Tags: php

```
$text = file_get_html('C:\text.txt');
echo str_replace(" ", "\n", $text);
```

Inside the text file is a bunch of random variables like this.

```
bob poop showoff noob hello world
```

I am trying to make a  new line but it's not working but just simply prints the same exact thing. I know \n is for illiterate and \n is for literate.

Comment: New lines on web page are not displayed. Check your script in a console.

Comment: It's not really clear what specific problem you're talking about.  How are you reading this file?  What are these "random variables" you mention?  Are you just asking how to make a newline character on Windows, or something else?  Is HTML involved here at all?

Comment: Sure it does https://3v4l.org/7Utjq

Comment: @Andreas That site simulates a console output. That's not a default behaviour of browsers.

Comment: @Magnus that is true. But in response to "simply prints the same exact thing", I'd say it's enough to answer that it's false.

Comment: @Magnus it's in the question. I quoted part of the question.

Comment: Just for completion: You may also have a look at the function `nl2br()` which adds html <br> tags before every new line in a string. But since you manually replace space by newline you could directly replace in by <br>.

Comment: @Andreas Ah, then I'm with you. I thought your comment was towards the commenters...  My bad! :)

Answer (score 3):

In html you get a new line with the `<br>` element not with `\n`.

```
echo str_replace(" ", "<br>", $text);
```

If you use you php script as a console script `\n` will work.
If this php script is used for a web page, the web browsers will ignore `\n` and look for `<br>`

Comment: So is \n basically useless in PHP? I thought it basically created new lines.

Comment: It's useless in HTML, not in PHP. You can also open PHP scripts in a console where \n is usefull

Comment: The \n will be visible in the code, could help visibility but in html, you will only see the <br> tag.

Comment: @NguyenjimboGamer No, it's not useless. There are different use-cases.

Comment: @NguyenjimboGamer: No, it's not useless.  It creates a new line.  But what are you *doing* with that output?  HTML and PHP are different things.

Answer (score 1):

The representation of a line break will be given by the output you want to generate; if you are generating a file use `\n` or `\r`, but if you want to output html, then:

> The `<br>` tag inserts a single line break.

[HTML < br> Tag](https://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_br.asp)